# Can C# call Volume Shadow Copy Service APIs (writer related), can how if yes?

Tags: c#, copy, volume-shadow-service

I'd like to query backup sources from certain VSS writer in my C# project. Is this possible? And how to do this if yes? I've searched google but did not find useful answers.
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and remove the visual-sourcesafe tag.

Comment: yes, i've edited the tag. it seems this site automatically change "VSS" to "visual source safe"...

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same answer.

For now, my fall back  idea is to compile the VSS writer in managed C++  so that from there I can call my C# codes. But, I am also looking to see if there are any alternates before trying that out.